# Isolate content of curly brackets which can contain nested curly brackets

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

In a TeX file, I've the following command `\q{aaa}{blablabla}` and I want to isolate the argument `blablabla`. I've figured it out using sed:

```
sed 's/\q{([^}\{])}{([^}\{])}/\2/g'
```

and it works well.

**The issue is** when there is *nested* curly brackets in the pattern I want to keep the inner curly brackets. In other words, in case of

```
\q{aaa}{blablabla \label{BBB}}
```

the desired output would be

```
blablabla \label{BBB}
```

We could imagine several LaTeX commands in a row I'd like to keep, for instance

```
\q{aaa}{blablabla \label{BBB} blablabla \includegraphics{ccc.eps} blablabla \cite{somebody_year} blablabla 
\begin{itemize}
\item AAA
\item BBB
\end{itemize}
blablabla to conclude}
```

The desired output for such an extreme MWE would be

```
blablabla \label{BBB} blablabla \includegraphics{ccc.eps} blablabla \cite{somebody_year} blablabla 
\begin{itemize}
\item AAA
\item BBB
\end{itemize}
blablabla to conclude
```

Such an example is a very (maybe too much) complicated one as the final goal of my search is to optimize revision of manuscrits (during the review process).

Not sure it can be done in a one-line `sed`...

Comment: Do you need the newlines preserved?

Comment: it is not mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal regular expressions can't do that; a language that requires balanced parenthesis isn't a *regular language* in the formal sense. So, you can't do that correctly with `sed`. Luckily things like Perl provide regexes that aren't actually limited to just regular languages.

E.g. this abomination (adapted from answer on SO to [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses) ) seems to match what you want:

```
perl -0 -lne 'print "$2\n\n" while m/ \\q\{aaa\} ( \{ ( (?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+ ) \} )/gx '
```

With the input `\q{aaa}{blablabla \label{BBB}} \foo{bar}{not this} \q{aaa}{bleh}` that gives the output

```
blablabla \label{BBB}

bleh
```

i.e. with the matching parts printed with two newlines inbetween. With `-0` as above, it should work with multiline tags too. You could also change `print $2` to `print $&` to get the full `\q{aaa}{...}` tag.

What this basically does, is that the beginning `\\q\{aaa\}` matches the constant part of the tag, and the inner part `(?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+` matches any number of things that are either a string with no braces, or something that can be matched by recursing at the first capture group (set of parenthesis), i.e. the matching pair of braces with something inside.

```
.../ \\q\{aaa\} ( \{ ( (?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+ ) \} )/ '
                ^1   ^2               |     ^2   ^1
                |                     |          |
                +---------------------+----------+ 
                        recurse to group 1
```

The second capture group is there to capture the part that's output.

Comment: Very impressive, it perfectly works and print the desired output. A question though... The one-line perl command prints what I want. But when I want to substitute in a file, the s command does not work (substitution replacement not terminated). In other words, why isn't it possible to to the following: perl  -pi.bak -e 's/ \\q\{.*\} ( \{ ( (?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+ ) \} )/gx' manuscrit_r1.tex

Comment: I got it: perl -pe 's/\\q\{.*} ( \{ ( (?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+ ) \} )/$2/gx' manuscrit_r1.tex